# Error while trying to use numpy, maybe because two version of python are installed?

Tags: linux-mint, python, python3

I'm new to Linux, I installed Mint 20.1.

The thing is that while trying to use some code using numpy I get this error:

[image]

I tried updating python and now it seems I have two versions of it.

If in terminal I type python3 I get this message

[image]

If I type python3.9 i see this

[image]

Maybe is because of this? I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: You need to install numpy for the version of Python that you are using and make sure that it is prepended to your `PATH`..

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Also, be aware that Pyhon2 and Python3 are installed in to their own separate places within your system for a reason--they are not cross-compatible. Install the version of numpy targeting the version of python you want to use (or install both, since they install to different locations and will not conflict).

Comment: @C.M. ok! i'll have that in mnind for future questions

Comment: @NasirRiley i finally changed interpreter path in vs code and now i can run the code correclty, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed interpreter path in vs code and now i can run the code correctly,